# How to find the product of the odd-indexed values in a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, reverse

I am able to solve this problem up the the 'even' part but I'm getting stuck in the odd part.

You will be given an array of `n` numbers. Your task is to first reverse the array (first number becomes last, 2nd number becomes 2nd from the last and so on) and then print the sum of the numbers at even indices and print the product of the numbers at odd indices.

Input

First line contains single integer N: number of elements
followed by N different integers separated by spaces

Output

Two space separated integers representing sum of the numbers at even places and the product of the numbers at odd places.

My code so far:

```py
n = int(input())
arr = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
arr.reverse()

for ele in arr:
    print(ele, end=" ")
print()

sum = 0
count = 1
while count <= n:
    if count % 2 == 0:
        sum += count
    count += 1
print(sum)
```

Comment: i m attaching my code till even indices                                                                                                       #####n=int(input())
arr=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
arr.reverse()
for ele in arr:
    print(ele, end=" ")
print()
sum=0
count=1
while count<=n:
    if count%2==0:
        sum+=count
    count+=1
print(sum)

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of issues in the code you've supplied which I'll address first:

Firstly, you need to be clear about what is meant by odd and even indices. In some languages (Matlab) for example, the first element of an array is index position 1. In Python and Java it's 0, so, whilst your example has assumed 1, it probably should be 0 unless otherwise specified.

Second, in your line `sum+=count` you're summing the index positions, not the index values, so that isn't what your question is asking for.

Last point on your code is that you've used `sum` as a variable name. Whilst that works, `sum` is also a Python keyword and you should avoid using them as variable names as if you later want to use the `sum` function, you will get the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` because you've redefined the `sum` function to be an integer.

To the answer:

Considering the above, this provides the answer to part 1 by fixing your code:

```py
total = 0
count = 0
while count < n:
    if count % 2 == 0:
        total += arr[count]
    count += 1
print(total)
```

It's worth noting that as you're looking for even numbers, you could better write that as:

```py
total = 0
count = 0
while count < n:
    total += arr[count]
    count += 2
print(total)
```

However, there are even easier ways to do this in much less code, and they involve *list slicing*. You can slice a list by specifying `[start: end: step]`, so `arr[::2]` specifies a start of position 0 (the default), an end of the end of the list the default) and a step of 2. This means that if `arr` contains `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, then `arr[::2]` will be `[1,3,5]` (i.e. the values at all of the even indices) or if you specify a start position of `1` i.e. `arr[1::2]` you will get `[2,4,6]` (i.e. the values at all of the even indices).

So, rather using a while loop. You could use a `for` loop over just the even values:

```py
total = 0
for even_val in arr[::2]:
    total += even_val
print(total)
```

but for `sum` you can even more easily write is as a simple `sum` command on the list slice:

```py
print(sum(arr[::2]))
```

Before Python 3.8, there was no simple equivalent of `sum` for product, so if you're using a lower version, you can either reuse the method above, allowing for the fact that you would need to prime the total with the first value, then multiply from the next one, i.e.:

```py
total = arr[1]
count = 3
while count < n:
    total *= arr[count]
    count += 2
print(total)
```

or with a `for` loop:

```py
total = arr[1]
for odd_val in arr[3::2]:
    total *= odd_val
print(total)
```

But from Python 3.8 (documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#math)) you can now import `prod` from the `math` library which will work in the same way as `sum`:

```py
from math import prod
print(prod(arr[1::2]))
```

[Thanks @HeapOverflow for the nudge]

As this is for a problem set, it may not be an issue as all examples may have an array length `N` > 2, but the examples above do assume that there will be at least two entries in `arr`. If that's not the case, you should put in some validation before trying to access `arr[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cute little recursive function to do that (assuming one-based indices):

```
# def prodSum(increment,multiplier=1,*rest): if zero based indices

def prodSum(multiplier,increment=0,*rest):  
    if not rest: return multiplier,increment
    product,total = prodSum(*rest)
    return (product * multiplier, total + increment)

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(prodSum(*reversed(x))) # 15,6
```